# JSON deserialisation – objects nested inside an array inside an object

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I want to deserialise an array of JSON objects. I followed [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/background-parsing) tutorial from Flutter documentation. The thing is, this array is nested inside an other object, and looks like this:

```
{
    "result":
    {
        "array":
        [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "here goes the string"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "another one here"
            } ...
```

I've been following [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/background-parsing) official tutorial, and I got stuck with an error:

> I/flutter (28639): AsyncSnapshot<List>(ConnectionState.done, null, Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments.
>
> I/flutter (28639): Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:2
>
> I/flutter (28639): Tried calling: cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()
>
> I/flutter (28639): Found: cast<Y0, Y1>() => Map<Y0, Y1>, #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:68:5)

I'd expect that I referenced poorly `.result.array[]` of that deserialised JSON `Map<String, dynamic>` thing, though the error shows up one line earlier, and I have completely no idea what's causing that. What might be the reason of this exception, and am I referencing to array in a good way?

My app basically looks like this (I've marked line in which exception is thrown by an arrow (→):

```
/* [...] */

Future<List<Models.Degree>> fetchDegrees(http.Client client) async
{
  final response = await client
      .get(Uri.parse("api uri here"));

  // Using the compute function to run in a separate isolate.
  return compute(parseDegrees, response.body);
}

List<Models.Degree> parseDegrees(String responseBody)
{
→  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed['result']['array'].map<Models.Degree>((json) => Models.Degree.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

/* [...] */

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Models.Degree>>(
        future: fetchDegrees(http.Client()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            print(snapshot.toString());
            return const Center(
              child: Text('An error has occurred!'),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return DegreesList(degrees: snapshot.data!);
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DegreesList extends StatelessWidget {
  const DegreesList({Key? key, required this.degrees}) : super(key: key);

  final List<Models.Degree> degrees;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: degrees.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text(degrees[index].name);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that tutorial the response body is:

```
[
 {
    "albumId": 100,
    "id": 4999,
    "title": "in voluptate sit officia non nesciunt quis",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/1b9d08",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/1b9d08"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 100,
    "id": 5000,
    "title": "error quasi sunt cupiditate voluptate ea odit beatae",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/6dd9cb",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/6dd9cb"
  }
]
```

The `jsonDecode` method returns `dynamic`.

In this case the type is `List<dynamic>`. List has a method `cast` https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-core/List/cast.html. So It works fine.

However in your case:

```
{
    "result": {
        "array": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "here goes the string"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "another one here"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

jsonDecode returns _InternalLinkedHashMap and this doesn't have a `cast` method, so it throws an exception.

You have many options, just to mention:

Just delete the `.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()` and it will work just fine.

You don't have to cast `responseBody` in order to use it because the "array" json key will have the type of `List<dynamic>` at the end, so you can use the `map` method without a problem.

But if you want to cast that anyways, you can use

```
final parsed = Map<String, dynamic>.from(jsonDecode(responseBody));
```